# I had installed installshield in my system but when i go to visual studio its not showing up in new project....why?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield

I had installed installshield in my system but when i go to visual studio->   file->new project , there is no installshield in new project...why its like that can any one give me a solution for that.I am using visual studio Express 2013.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Express doesn't support extensions / addins / project templates and so on.  Switch to Visual Studio Community Edition or better.